# Why does TS let me return wrong type in overloaded function declarations?

Tags: typescript

I think the question is clear enough and here is the code that makes me wonder:

```js
type T = {
  (value: number): number
  (value: string): string
}
```

#### First Example

```js
const bar: T = (value: any) => {
  if (typeof value === "number") return []
  return value
}
bar(10) // []
```

For me it is inconsistent that the compiler then throws an error in the following example:

#### Second Example

```js
const bar: T = (value: any) => {
  return []
}
```

Why can I return `[]` in the first example but get an error if I return `[]` in the second example?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`any` opts out of type checking. By using it, you're effectively telling Typescript to not care about type checking for the code paths that use it.

When you return an `any` type (as you are with `value`), Typescript will skip checking if it matches the declared return type. However, when you return an explicit empty array (as in your second example), that is a known type, not an `any`, so Typescript can check if it matches the declared return type.

Comment: I already thought about that. But why does it throw an error if do the following instead? `const bar: T = (value: any) => {
  return []
}`

Comment: Because `[]` is an array literal of type Array, not `value` of type `any`, so Typescript can typecheck it. There is no array type in `T`.

Comment: I still don't understand your explanation which comes after *However...* in your sentence unfortunately. Because you say if I *return an explicit empty array...*, but I am doing this in the first example in the `if` statement as well. There is no difference.

Comment: Why does the TS compiler even permit to assign a function with an `any` parameter to `bar` when the type `T` restricts it to `number` or `string`?

Comment: The first `if` statement uses `value`, which is of type `any`, so Typescript stops type checking at that point. To reach that return value, you must go through a code path that turns off type checking. `any` is really just a concession to allow for the gradual upgrade of Javascript to Typescript, and really shouldn't be used except in cases where the types truly can't be known ahead of time (such as parsing network call payloads). The compiler doesn't know how you'll use the `any` parameter, so why would it forbid it?

Comment: Thank you Chris, your last comment helped a lot. @zett42 I believe this is because of the way call signature overloading works in TypeScript. If you declare a set of overload
signatures for a function f, from a caller’s point of view f’s type is the union of those overload signatures. But from f’s implementation’s point of view, there needs to be a single, combined type that can actually be implemented. You need to manually declare this combined call signature when implementing f—it won’t be inferred for you.

Comment: I see my mistake in thinking. Even if you assign a function with an `any` parameter, type checking at the call side of `bar` is still in place. Anyway, a function that excepts an `any` parameter should be able to handle either `number` or `string`.

Comment: _The first if statement uses value, which is of type any, so Typescript stops type checking_ Not really, the only "problem" is returning variable of type `any`

Answer (score 1):

If return type of the function is not specified (like in example above), typescript will infer the return type by creating union of possible return values' types.

So we have union of `[]` and `any`. Union of `any` type with whatever other type will result in `any`

```
type Result = any | []; // any
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBDAdiKAPlANoC6QA)

Now our function's signature resolved as `(value: any) => any` therefore assignment to variable of type `T` is allowed.

* This has nothing to do with overloads.

Comment: The still not quite answered question is: Why can I return `[]` in OP's first example but it throws an error if I return `[]` in the second example.

Comment: @Take because in first example the function type is resolved to `(value: any) => any` (as explained above) and it is assignable to `T`, but in the second example the function type is resolved to `(value: ant) => []` which is not assignable to `T`

Comment: Ok, this would explain why the compiler complains. But why are they resolved differently? I mean in both cases I return the object `[]`, what exactly in my code causes these two different resolutions? I know that the union of `any | []` is `any`.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBDAdiKAPlANoC6AUOaJFACoZQDe5UUAFAG5bKIQBcUHIgC2AIwgAnAJQChYyS3Zce-KPGASAljgDmMtRu07yAX0oATCAGNkWCdCsB7HOqgAzR44GduvAbhApDAA+bDwAbnJLGzsHZ1dRO29lPzDAkJJSSPJkCDRgAXpMD0dwqAB6cqgAeQBpKgZEiTLKqABRCQlHCSA) will help you to understand

Comment: _in both cases I return []_ - if you'll look at resolved function's signature - the return type is `any` or `[]` (union of `any` and `[]`), **not only** `[]`

Comment: Oh damn, I get it now! Thank you a lot! It was like an invisible barrier in my head.